# dell power connect 3524 switch SNMP port mapping

Tags: switch, dell, snmp

I am using MibViewer utility and executing SNMP Walk command using OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2 to find which MAC addresses are connected to which ports on my switch.

What I am seeing is that for every walk request the switch seems to return inconsistent results every time. Out of the 24 live ports on the switch it only returns mappings for some of the ports each time.

Why doesn't it always return every port mapping each time?

I have a program which has to sit there and execute SNMP get command sometimes for up to 10 minutes before it can get all 24 ports mapped.

I would like to find a more efficient, faster way to retrieve all of the port to MAC address mappings.

Comment: dmg, when you say that you are getting inconsistent results... are the result different than what you see from a simultaneous CLI query?

Comment: I have several PowerConnect 3548 switches all very busy, and I don't see this behavior.  I actually didn't know you could retrieve this data over SNMP although I can see the application for it.  I'd suspect it's a bug and if you have support on your device, report the bug to Dell; if not, post what results you're seeing here so we can at least learn from it. Finally, upgrade your firmware, Dell has fixed several bugs between 2009 and 2012 on these switches, one of which took my network down last week.

Answer (score 0):

A PowerConnect 35XX? That must be a new model. Seriously, are you trying to keep the model number a secret?

In any event, the 35XX series switches are managed switches so why not just log in to the web interface and look at the Dynamic Address table?

Is it a requirement to have a programattic way of interrogating the address table?

Comment: To be exact it is a 3524 switch.

Comment: Yeah, i do have to have a programmatic way of doing this because i need to bring this information to the user's attention in real time